# why quicktime video don't play in moodle

Tags: moodle

Using Moodle, can play .flv file but can't paly quick time video foarm and force downlaod.
I want to direct play in website.pls,suggestion me

Answer (score 0):

You can use JW player plugin  to upload quick time video. Even you can use media plugin which is in Moodle plugin site to upload videos.